# Invisible memory error in C++ sieve code

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging, memory-leaks

I have written a very basic sieve of eratosthenes with C++, however when the `n` is `1000000` (a million), the code crashes. I could not resolve the issue and now in need of help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    long n = 1000000,i ,j;
    vector<bool> arr(n, true);

    for(i = 2; i * i < n; i++){

        if(arr[i]){
            for(j = i + i; j <= n; j += i){
                arr[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Made it here." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Some info:**

- I compile with x64 mingw (Windows 10) compiler.
- Using -O2, disabling makes no difference
- `n = 100000` or `n = 10000000` does not give errors (very strange) and code works fine, so values more than a million does not give problems while one million gives an error (crash).
- Code can print `"Made it here."`
- Tried making the vector global (thinking about local memory limit problem), no avail.
- Used DrMemory for debugging, it showed one error `1 total unaddressable access(es)`, which I could not find.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** A more informing description of the error from Drmemory

`Error #1: UNADDRESSABLE ACCESS beyond heap bounds: writing 0x0000000003921608-0x000000000392160c 4 byte(s)`

Comment: @Justin, It would make me sad, if that was the error :( I was prepared for something big, maybe thats why I missed it).

Comment: ^ What @Justin said. Also, you can change the initialization statement to `j=i*i` instead of `j=i+i`.

Comment: what confused me is, the code is pretty deterministic, but consecutive runs of the program sometimes presented error and sometimes not.

Comment: Undefined behavior.  The code is not deterministic when you make mistakes like this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for(j = i + i; j <= n; j += i){
>     arr[j] = false;
> ```

What happens when `j == n`? You access `arr[n]`, which is out of bounds, as `arr.size() == n`.

This is *undefined behavior*. Your program may crash, or it may silently continue, or it may do something else. You can't reason about what will happen, because – by definition – the behavior isn't defined.

Comment: Thank you, it's not my original problem but I have another question, I want to examine how much memory did this program used in it's peak. I know it can be calculated but I need to measure using some tools, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @MaxPaython I don't know if Dr Memory has that ability, but the "equivalent" (I've heard Dr Memory is equivalent to) on Unix is *valgrind*, which can tell you that. Maybe Dr Memory has an option to record that information.